# dvi file is not created in texmaker

Tags: pdftex, texmaker, dvi

I use texmaker but when I compile the source file normally I get the pdf as result and I did not know that I should received also DVI file but now i need the dvi file for a conference but i cannot get it. what is the problem? is there any command there?

Comment: You have to run `latex` instead of `pdflatex`. Change it near the first blue arrow or use the tools menu. http://i.stack.imgur.com/adX4j.png

Comment: Alternatively with `pdflatex -output-format dvi aa.tex` it gives .dvi file

Comment: @Sigur You can probably just write an answer. (You could also mention the keyboard shortcut F2.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to run `latex` instead of `pdflatex`. Change it near the first blue arrow (below the Help menu) or use the Tools menu, as shown in figure below. Also, as noted by @Torbjørn T., you can use the keyboard shortcuts.

[image]

Comment: of course but i used pdf files and dvi file will not generate with these file therefore i produced my figures in eps and it worked.

Comment: @user32422, you're right. You should use `eps` figures with `latex` to produce `dvi` files. If you'll send the `dvi` file don't forget to send also the `eps` figures since they are not imbedded in `dvi`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to options quick build. There is a option latex+view dvi. Please click on it. It works for me. Only I have a problem is with printing.